# Using braces in verbatim environment

Tags: verbatim, braces

I want to put some code in a verbatim environment:

```
\begin{verbatim}
data _≥_ : Nat → Nat → Set where
  ge0 : {y : Nat}                   → y     ≥ zero
  geS : {x : Nat} {y : Nat} → x ≥ y → suc x ≥ suc y
\end{verbatim}
```

but when I compile the document I get warnings saying that { and } are not defined for this font:

> ./3-proofs.tex:0:No file OMScmtt.fd. on input line 116.
>
> ./3-proofs.tex:116: Font shape `OMS/cmtt/m/n' undefined(Font) using`OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead(Font) for symbol `textbraceleft' on input line 116. Font shape`OMS/cmtt/m/n' undefined(Font) using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead(Font) for symbol`textbraceleft'
>
> dep-typed-wbl-heaps.tex:0: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

Somewhere on the web I found a hint to add

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

to my document, but that completely messes up huge portions of my text and therefore is not an option. Is there any other way to get curly braces in verbatim environment?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Try with `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using that.

Comment: @karlkoeller `inputenc` has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @JanStolarek I've never seen `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` messing things up. If you mean that the fonts become jaggy, then it's because your TeX distribution misses the CM-Super fonts. Add also `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Comment: @egreg Simply I didn't read the question carefully...